# Composite key in Entity Framework using sqlite in uwp

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, composite-primary-key

I am developing an uwp app. I am using entity models to create tables in sqlite database. I have a situation with a table where 2 columns make up the primary key. But I am not able to create a table with composite key.

The code I have used for table creation is:

```
public class Denomination_Master
{
        [MaxLength(50), NotNull]
        public string den_name { get; set; }
        [NotNull,PrimaryKey]
        public float den_value { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Indexed]
        public string den_type { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(250), Default(value: null)]
        public string den_image { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(250), Default(value: null)]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [Default(value: null)]
        public string created_date { get; set; }
        [Default(value: null)]
        public string updated_date { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(80), Default(value: null)]
        public string role_name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(80), Default(value: null)]
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4), Default(value: null)]
        public bool? status { get; set; }
}

using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
{
    conn.CreateTable<Denomination_Master>();
}
```

https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL here I found something like this:

```
    public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

But my column datatype is not int how can apply this.?

Comment: I only see a **single column** (`den_value`) being part of the primary key - so this is really not a composite primary key. Your question is very unclear......

Comment: den_value is a primarykey but I want to put primary key for den_type also I think I have to use composite primary key for that.

Comment: @Archana are you using Microsoft Entity Framework or the ORM embedded in SQLite?

Comment: ORM embedded in SQLite

Comment: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL here I found something like this:                                                                                            public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your composite key using the fluent API, you cannot use attributes for composite primary keys.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Denomination_Master>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.den_value, c.den_type });
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys